# php, I need child object from parent, how?

Tags: php, oop, object, parent

```
class Parent
{
 public function exec()
 {
  // here I need the child object!
 }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
 public function exec()
 {
  // something
  parent::exec();
 }
}
```

as you can see, I need the child object from the parent. How can I reach it?

Comment: If a `Child` isn't actually a subset of a `Parent`, and you're instead just looking to establish a hierarchy between objects, you need a data structure like a tree or linked list, not inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the child as an argument:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function exec( $child )
    {
        echo 'Parent exec';
        $child->foo();
    }
}

class Child extends ParentClass
{
    public function exec()
    {
        parent::exec( $this );
    }

    public function foo() 
    {
        echo 'Child foo';
    }
}
```

This is rarely needed though, so there might be a better way to do [what you're trying to do](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).